# Universally embedding total order = $\eta_\xi$ set?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

In Alling's "Foundations of Analysis on Surreal Number Fields," he writes

> If $X$ is an $\eta_\xi$-set and if $Y$ is a [totally] ordered set of power not exceeding $\aleph_\xi$, then there exists an order-preserving map $f$ of $Y$ into $X$.

In other words, every $\eta_\xi$ set is universally embedding for every totally ordered set of cardinality $\leq \aleph_\xi$.

Is the converse true? Do we have that for every totally ordered set that is universally embedding for cardinality up to $\aleph_\xi$, that it is also an $\eta_\xi$ set?

EDIT: an $\eta_\xi$ set is a totally ordered set which has the property that, for every pair of subsets $L$ and $R$ such that everything in $L$ < everything in $R$, if $L$ and $R$ are of cardinality less than $\aleph_\xi$, then for all $l \in L$ and $r \in R$, there exists $z$ such that $l < z < r$. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%97_set

Comment: What is an $\eta_\xi$ set? (Note that any order into which an $\eta_\xi$ set embeds is also $\le\aleph_\xi$-universally embedding, so if $\eta_\xi$-ness isn't preserved by passing to a larger linear order we get an immediate answer.)

Comment: I'm referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%97_set

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying now. You can embed an $\eta_\psi$ set into some larger set that isn't $\eta_\psi$ by just adding a bunch of junk elements off to the end or something. Such a set will still let the other sets embed into it, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

If $L$ is $\le\aleph_\xi$-universally embedding, then so is every linear order into which $L$ embeds. So a negative answer to the question follows from showing that linear orders containing $\eta_\xi$-sets need not be $\eta_\xi$-sets themselves. This can be done in many ways; for example, given an $\eta_\xi$-set $A$, consider the linear order $2\cdot A$ gotten by replacing each point in $A$ by a pair of adjacent points.

Incidentally, we can consistently do even better: there can consistently be $\le\aleph_\xi$-universally embedding linear orders without any $\eta_\xi$-subsets. Specifically, fix some enumeration $(L_\theta)_{\theta<\kappa}$ of linear orders such that each linear order of size $\le\aleph_\xi$ appears as some $L_\theta$ (and $\kappa$ is an ordinal). The sum $$X=\sum_{\theta<\kappa}L_\theta$$ is then trivially $\le\aleph_\xi$-universally embedding (although really what this shows is that [that's the wrong notion of universal embedding to consider](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410437/what-does-it-mean-for-the-surreal-numbers-partizan-games-to-be-universally-embe/410471#410471)). Now $X$ only has an $\eta_\xi$-subset if there is an $\eta_\xi$-set of cardinality $\le\aleph_\xi$, and in general there need not be.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber. That stronger notion of embedding seems very interesting, where any embedding of $A$ into $X$ can be extended to an embedding of $B$ into $X$ that preserves $A$'s embedding whenever $A$ embeds into $B$. Does that give us some nice characterization in terms of $\eta$ sets, e.g. this notion of universal embedding is equivalent to having an $\eta_\xi$ subset or something like that?

Comment: Hm, I do think this stronger notion of universal embedding is related to being an $\eta_\psi$ set, but I am not exactly clear on what the stronger notion is. The idea is that for any linearly ordered set $S$ you want to embed it into your universally embedding set $X$ in such a way that extensions of your order, let's call them $T$ with $S \subset T$, also embed into $X$ preserving the embedding on $S$.

Comment: But is the idea behind "strongly universal embedding" for $X$ that for *every* embedding of $S$ into $X$, the embedding can be extended to an embedding of $T$ preserving $S$? Or just that, for any $S \subset T$, there always exists *at least one* embedding of $S$ into $X$ that can be extended to an embedding of $T$, in addition to other embeddings that potentially don't?

Comment: I would guess you mean the former, since the latter would again include your example of the sum of all linear orders of cardinality at most $\aleph_\xi$. Then I think we have that any $X$ which strongly embeds all linearly ordered sets up to *but not including* cardinality $\aleph_\xi$ would be an $\eta_\xi$ set. So $\Bbb Q$, for instance, strongly embeds all finite linear orders, but doesn't *strongly* embed all countable linear orders - for instance the identity embedding of $\Bbb Q$ to itself can't be strongly extended to anything else. But it does weakly embed all countable linear orders.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The idea is indeed the former: that every embedding can always be extended. The precise definition I have in mind is the following: say that $\mathcal{X}$ *(a single structure)* **strongly universally embeds** $\mathbb{K}$ *(a class of structures of the same type)* iff every element of $\mathbb{K}$ embeds into $\mathcal{X}$ and for every $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\in\mathbb{K}$ and every pair of embeddings $f:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ and $g:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ there is an embedding $h:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ such that $hg\supseteq f$.

Comment: *(This is related to the **amalgamation property** in the setting of Fraisse limits and ages.)* E.g. as you say, the linear order $\mathbb{Q}$ does **not** strongly universally embed the class of all countable linear orders, even though every countable linear order embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$ (indeed no infinite structure $\mathcal{X}$ ever strongly universally embeds the class of all structures of cardinality $\le\vert\mathcal{X}\vert$).

Comment: OK, thank you for clarifying. So then I think that any linear order that is "strongly universally embedding" for all linear orders of cardinality $ < \aleph_\xi$ is an $\eta_\xi$ set and vice versa. The basic idea is, take any two linear orders $A$ and $B$ both of cardinality less than $\aleph_\xi$. Then we have to be able to embed $A$, $B$, $A + B$, and let's say $A + \{1\} + B$, where $\{1\}$ is just a linear order with one point. The embedding of $A + B$ can be viewed as a "cut", and must be extensible to another embedding with a point between A and B, meaning it's an $\eta_\xi$ set. (1/2)

Comment: For the other way: we already know that any $\eta_\xi$ set is "weakly embedding" for linear orders of cardinalities $\leq \alpha_\xi$. It is also easy to see that, given any linear embedding, you can extend it to add "one more point" anywhere you want. So if you want to extend $A$ to any $B$ such that $A \subset B$, you can set up an ordinal enumeration of $B - A$, and then just keep adding points one at a time. Since the result at each stage will be of cardinality less than $\aleph_\xi$, even when all of $B$ is added, you can keep doing this, thus it's strongly embedding. Is that the idea?